# Extending Boost intervals to scalar multiplication

Tags: c++, performance, boost

I am sure the answer to this question is simple, but I don't get the gist of c++ yet, so sorry if this is stupid or has already been answered.

I have an `Eigen` vector of `Boost` intervals, given by

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>

namespace bn = boost::numeric;
namespace bi = bn::interval_lib;

using Interval = bn::interval<
        double,
        bi::policies<
            bi::save_state<bi::rounded_transc_std<double> >,
            bi::checking_base<double>
        >
    >;
using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 3, 3>;
using Vector = Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 3, 1>;
```

I want to be able to take usual matrix/vector products of these vectors with usual vectors of doubles. Ultimately I also want an inner product. 
But right now, boost intervals don't seem to support an operand multiplication for interval and double. My question is, how would I go on about overloading said multiplication?
The following solution works

```
Interval operator* (double x, const Interval& y)
    {
        double lower;
        double upper;
        lower = x*y.lower();
        upper = x*y.upper();
        if(upper>lower){ return Interval(lower,upper);}
        else{ return Interval(upper,lower); }
    }
```

But I am concerned about the *performance* and want to hear opinions on a maybe better way.
Further, to define the multiplication for scalar and interval vectors, I would have chosen to just loop through the interval elements and use the interval times scalar multiplication from above in place, which seems not very efficient. Is there a more natural, faster, more c++ish way to do this? Will I have to overload more operators to be able to use methods like std::inner_product on two vectors with interval and double entries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend you posting your question in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You will probably get also very interesting answers and proposals

Comment: why are you using intervals in the first place ? unless it's just to simplify error analysis, algebraically the set of intervals is not a field, so the result of most linear algebra algorithms would be hardly meaningful ... moreover, if you want performance you'd better recast the original problem as a linear one, to exploit already existing optimized implementations (like Eigen's)...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I need to write an algorithm to find zeros of functions R^n->R^m with certainty and I want to use interval newton combined with an initial divide and conquer for this. Interval newton requires a step with such algebraic operations and for evaluation of an interval enclosure function those are also helpful (like f(vec(x)) = sin(vec(x)*vec(k)) )

Comment: "*[...]with certainty*" keep in mind that floating point arithmetic is precise, but not accurate. That is, even if you work with intervals your results will be still affected by some systematic error; if you want exact/arbitrarily accurate arithmetic, you need an exact/arbitrarily accurate arithmetic type. Even then, it still depends on the kind of functions you want to analyze (not all mathematical entities can be faithfully modeled by a computer ) ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes That's not entirely true, at least not in the way that I mean "with certainty". There's a theorem surrounding the interval newton version that says from a specific condition on the interval resulting from the step one can say with certainty that the interval contains exactly one root. Aside from that, I need interval arithmetic for later purpose in an algorithm I'm trying to implement and where I see no way to go without it. Also, with proper roundings and inclusion functions, I don't see how they could be not accurate in at least finding all roots in certain intervals.

Comment: @bernhard_e even assuming a perfectly conformant iee754 floating point implementation, you'll need specially crafted theorems (and a deep knowledge of iee754 arithmetic) in order to prove something "with certainty". If you can live with that, or you just want something to work "reliably", then you're fine of course :)

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I'm not sure we mean the same thing when we say "with certainty". But as you put it, I guess I'm fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function redefines the library operator:

```
Interval operator*(double x, const Interval &y) {
    return x * y;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdf5957e7a9ec785)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>

namespace bi = boost::numeric::interval_lib;

using Interval = boost::numeric::interval<
    double, bi::policies<
        bi::save_state<bi::rounded_transc_std<double> >, bi::checking_base<double> 
    > >;

#include <boost/numeric/interval/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Interval i{1.9, 2.1};
    std::cout << (2.0 * i) << "\n";
    std::cout << (i * 2.0) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
[3.8,4.2]
[3.8,4.2]
```

Comment: I see, so I would have had to include the io.hpp, I didn't know that. Thank you, that helps.

Comment: However, to combine a "usual" vector, say Eigen::Vector3d, with the costum type Vector in a scalar product or the likes, I really need to redefine multiplication of those, right? Or am I missing some obvious include/ trick again?

Comment: Huh?!? No. The include is (obviously) to [print the output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f56d525a60f2573) only. Did you use `double` as the scalar?

Comment: no you're right, it works without that. I must have done something else wrong.. C++ is still very confusing to me.

Comment: I found my mistake. I had used floats instead of doubles. For floats I get the said operand overload error.